# How to make an element disappear by clicking off it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a search that displays results right underneath it in a div that displays above other elements on the page (like an auto-complete or the address bar on chrome). I want to the results to stay visible wherever the mouse is, but disappear if the user clicks outside the search box or outside the results themselves. How can I do this?

Comment: I believe your looking to hide on the focus out event.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Old one but it should work https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-outside-events/

Comment: I really just have an input field. I was looking for some direction as to what css properties or javascript/jquery functions could help solve this--I think the focus functions are what I was looking for. 
edit: something like that plugin, yes, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `.blur()` event I believe. http://jsfiddle.net/d7mbbmwe/

```
$('#input1').blur(function() {
    $('.results').html('')
});
```